# Какие есть ограничения для base64 данных?

Tags: html, base64

Написал код который в `embed` загружает PDF файл в **base64** формате. Если файл скажем 150 килобайт, то он отображается без проблем, а 2 мегабайт уже не отображается или вешает страницу. Может быть это связано с каким нибудь ограничением?

Вот так я вывожу PDF файл (javascript):

```js
function printPdfFile(data){
 var widthImage = 1024;
 var heightImage = 768;
 var newWin = open('','Печать файла','width='+ widthImage +',height='+ heightImage  + ',status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbar=0,resizable=yes');

 newWin.document.writeln('<html><head></head><body><embed name="plugin" src="data:application/pdf;base64,' + data + '" id="pdfDocument" width="100%" height="100%"></embed></ body></html>');
 newWin.document.close();
 newWin.focus();
}
```

Comment: покажите как Вы загружаете pdf (Ваш код), а также это проявляется только в конкретном браузере или во всех?

Comment: @Alex добавил в вопрос, на firefox эта проблема существует у всех пользователей. на других браузерах не проверял